# How to create jar file and run mapreduce code in hadoop (i am having map,reduce and driver function codes in separate files)

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I downloaded code from [Cloud era website](http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/other/tutorial/CDH5/Hadoop-Tutorial/ht_example_4_sentiment_analysis.html)
and i am running single node cluster in hadoop.  I don't know how to compile and run the code.. please help me out..

Answer (score 1):

**in commandline-**

```
jar cfe myJar.jar myClass diver.class map.class reduce.class
```

**in eclipse**

right click on project

 go to  export
 [image]